# Which version of ROS is needed?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper

https://github.com/MobileRobotics-Ulaval/husky-trainer

The first package specifies Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic.
The second specifies ROS Hydro or Indigo. (and Ubuntu 14.04)

Does this mean it's impossible to use them together?

In other words: I was hoping to use Husky-trainer (on a different machine, similar to the Husky) with the ZED stereo camera (and no laser) but I see ZED's latest ROS packages specify Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic. It seems ROS Indigo wants Ubuntu 14.04. I am using the NVIDIA Jetson TX1.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257157/which-version-of-ros-is-needed?/) by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2017-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've never used the Zed wrapper but looking at the github page and going to the [v1.0.0 tag](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper/tree/v1.0.0), it looks like version 1.0.0 works with Indigo (it's mentioned in the README.md).

I know that the Husky doesn't have support yet for Kinetic from this question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/253648/ros-kinetic-husky-question/). So I think your best option is to install Indigo and try that v1.0.0 of the Zed wrapper. Even if Clearpath did finish the Husky's support for Kinetic soon, who knows if MobileRobotics-Ulaval will update husky-trainer.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2017-03-16**:
Thanks for this! Plug-and-Play these things are not, yet!